# Oledb Connection is getting error when I use go statement in sql query

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

We are using the bulk set of sql script in a sql file and load that file during runtime to text variable in C#. Hence I execute the following query through Oledb Connection and Command type
as "Text". Unfortunatly It was given the following error.

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

SQL Query Syntax

```
  IF exists  (
                SELECT  '1' 
                FROM    sysobjects 
                WHERE   id = object_id(N'SP_Name')  
                and     objectproperty(id, N'isprocedure') = 1
               )
    BEGIN
        DROP PROC SP_Name 
    END
    GO
    Create PROCEDURE SP_Name 
     (  
       @var_id NUMERIC(10),
       @var_id1 NVARCHAR(100),
       @var_id_Out1     numeric(10)     output,
       @var_id_Out2     integer         output,
       @var_id_Out3     nvarchar(2000)  output
    )  
    WITH ENCRYPTION  
    AS  
    BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON  
        select * from demotable
    SET NOCOUNT OFF  
    END 
    GO

GRANT   EXEC ON SP_Name TO PUBLIC
GO
```

C# Code snippet

```
OleDbCommand cmd;
OleDbConnection co = new OleDbConnection("Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=servername;Database=DB_Name;User Id=sa;Password=mypass;");
co.Open();
String[] strFileList = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\Procedure");
String conntent = null;
foreach (string commandSP in strFileList)
{
       conntent = File.ReadAllText(commandSP);
       cmd = co.CreateCommand();
       cmd.CommandText = conntent;     
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
co.Close();
```

Answer (score 2):

the GO command is T-SQL syntax ... that is interpreted by the frontend to separate batches ... neither OLEDB nor the server will understand that statement ...

for getting this to work with OLEDB you can split the batches yourself and run each batch individualy

Comment: The problem is if I use the OSQL utility I can execute the t-sql statment with GO statement. But my concern I wouldn't use OSQL for one of my requirement. I couldn't do it seperate patch mechanism because I've huge number of sql's which inside has very big sql statements. Spiliting will take a time and may have a possibility error thrown.

Comment: Simple speaking I need a alternative for OSQL through C#

Comment: either split them, or use a connection that supports the statement

Comment: if you want to avoid splitting, and need it executed as is ... you can call a commandline tool: sqlcmd ... the only other thing i know that can interpret GO was sql dmo, but that's depricated by now and doesn't support newer sql server versions

Answer (score 2):

GO isn't a T-SQL keyword i.e. it's not part of the language, it's simply a token used by some clients (e.g. Management Studio) to separate batches